# What tags will be included in our November contest?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion, contest

As previously [announced](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/748/lets-hold-a-contest) and [discussed](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11473761#11473761), we'll be holding a contest in November (coinciding with [National Novel Writing Month](http://nanowrimo.org/)), and we'll be focusing on expanding our content on the topic of **specific fiction genres**.

Participation in the contest will be any questions and answers written during the contest period, within the following set of tags:

[childrens](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/childrens)
[comedy](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comedy)
[fantasy](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy)
[science-fiction](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction)
[historical](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical)
[horror](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horror)
[mystery](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mystery)
[romance](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/romance)
[thriller](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thriller)
[young-adult](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/young-adult)

If I've missed anything or made errors in this list, let me know in answers and comments.

Comment: Added: [tag:fan-fiction].